# Kivy, Label text and multithreading

Tags: kivy

I've put a loop into thread and I want my label to show the given thext. The issue is that it doesn't show most of texts I see in the terminal. It shows only:

```
>Text 0
>nothing
>Text 4
>Text 5
>nothing
>text 14
>text 15
>etc.
```

I've no idea why is that. I tried to use `Clock.schedule_once` to call `prompt` function but the resoult is the same.

**CODE**

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import threading
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from time import sleep

kv = '''

<MainWindow>
    Button:
        text: 'Go!'    
        on_press: root.go()
    Label:
        id: label
 
MainWindow:   
'''

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

    def go(self):
        thread = Prompter()
        thread.start()

    def prompt(self, text):
        self.ids.label.text = text
        print(self.ids.label.text)

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(100):
            text = 'TEXT {}'.format(i)
            App.get_running_app().root.prompt(text)
            sleep(0.5)

class Setup(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Setup().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `@mainthread` decorator to the `prompt()` method. Changes to the GUI must be done on the min thread.

Comment: I thought I do it in mainthread with line `App.get_running_app().root.prompt(text)`. I've tried with the decorator but label still shows only: `0, 4, 5...`

Comment: Ok I've checked by `threading.current_thread() is threading.main_thread()` and it is `False`. I thought that it is just a matter of passing `text` to right `object`. So now I'm going to work out how to do it in main thread.

Comment: It seems it is not an threading issue. It think the problem was with kivy.deps.sdl2 version 0.1.20. With 0.1.21 I get an 'Fail to get valuable window provider' so I've installed 0.1.18 and with that it works.